# How can I make parentheses stick to formula?

Tags: brackets

I'm working with a class of functions roughly denoted by

```
\mathcal R\big(\Pi_+;\le\big).
```

The problem is that the last parenthesis won't "stick" to the rest. What I mean by that is that i.e. when the expression stands at the end of a line, then the `\big)` part will slip into the next line. Or when I use a `\linebreak` somewhere, then it really gets torn apart right at the last parenthesis, if that makes sense. It's quite important to me to use bigger parentheses than the normal ones.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `\nobreak` before the paren.  Also `\bigl` and `\bigr` to give a sense to the open/close nature of parens.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx 
xxxxxxx $\mathcal R\bigl(\Pi_+;\le\bigr).$

xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx 
xxxxxxx $\mathcal R\bigl(\Pi_+;\le\nobreak\bigr).$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You're not using `\le` in its standard role of a binary relation symbol. Brace it, so it will be treated as an ordinary symbol after which no line break is possible.

Besides, you should be using `\bigl` and `\bigr`, not the simple `\big`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\parbox{0pt}{% to force as many line breaks as possible
$\mathcal{R}\bigl(\Pi_+;{\le}\bigr)$
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

or put your math expression into `\mbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx
xxxxxxx \mbox{$\mathcal{R}\bigl(\Pi_+;\le\bigr)$}.
xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx
xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx
\end{document}
```

[image]